# How long will it take a domain to become available after showing a status of pendingdelete / redemptionperiod?

Tags: domain, domain-registrar, domain-registration

I'm trying to secure a .co domain and it shows it expired on 12/22/2020.

Registry Status:

clienttransferprohibited / pendingdelete / redemptionperiod

I understand it goes through various updates at can take 45 days before it's available. Does this suggest the domain will be available on the 5th February (12/22/2020 + 45 days)?

Thanks

Jonathan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The process depend by registrar sadly. It can be from 30 to 70 days.

Godaddy fact seem to state 30 days, but ICANN is more open ended;

A note; If hosted on godaddy I would suggest to leave a bid, as it seem to check bid before releasing the domain to the public.

[image]

Comment: Q so EPP state #clienttransferprohibited is under "Redemption Grace Period" ?